# How is it possible to test SOAP (wsdl) client?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I'm working on a soap client. I have a `.wsdl` file, which defines the operations and types.

The server is not available.

How is it possible to create a test server based on that `.wsdl` file, which responds to the requests and sends back random but valid data? Does a tool with this functionality exists?

Comment: Hi, did this work? if it did request you to please mark as answered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SOAPUI to create a stub / mock service using the wsdl and use that for testing. https://www.soapui.org/soap-mocking/working-with-mockservices.html